# node.js: Cannot find module 'it-is'

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, module, require

i'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/maxogden/conversationThreading-js/blob/master/jwz_test.js) node.js unit tests and i get this error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'it-is'
```

from the code it's obvious that this 'it-is' module is a unit test module.. ie

```
var it = require('it-is');
...
it("Subject").equal(util.normalizeSubject("Re[2]:Subject"));
```

however it's pretty much impossible to google such a framework because google simply strips out the 'it-is' part.. and i search the node.js unit tests couldn't find something called 'it-is'..

help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that project is missing a `package.json` file to specify its dependencies.

Therefore, you need to install them yourself:

```
npm install underscore
npm install it-is
```